# Generically get the name of the current class?

Tags: c#, this

When logging data, I want a generic reference to the containing class. That way, if the code is moved elsewhere, the class name will change accordingly. (Otherwise, if the code moves to `nameof(Class2)`, it will still be logged incorrectly as `nameof(Class1)`). For example:

```
class Class_Name {
   ICommand Command_Name =>
        new RelayCommand(() =>
        {
           // An loggable event occurs

           // Is there a smart and uncomplicated way of doing this generically?
           var provenance = $"{nameof(Class_Name)}.{nameof(Command_Name)}";

           // The event of whatever kind gets logged
      });
   }

   // OR
   void Method_Name() {
      var provenance = $"{nameof(Class_Name)}.{nameof(Method_Name)}";
   }
}
```

Using a generic `nameof(this)`, where `this` should refer to the class itself, causes a compilation error: *CS8081: Expression does not have a name*. Using `this.GetType()` causes the same problem.

Not really understanding why the `this` keyword does not refer to the containing class in this context. Is there a way to refer to the current class generically?

Comment: Instead of using `$"{nameof(this.GetType())}"` use `$"{this.GetType().Name}"`.

Comment: @mcjmzn *CS8082: Sub-expression cannot be used in an argument to nameof.* As expressed earlier in post, `this.GetType()` is not accessible in the first place. The `this` keyword seems inaccessible inside `nameof()`.

Comment: @mcjmzn I forgot to specify, this is in an `ICommand`, not in a method, the example is incorrect, your solution would work. Will edit the post.

Comment: What I mean is: you should not combine the `nameof` with `this.GetType()`. Use `this.GetType().Name` to get the class name.

Comment: @mcjmzn my apologies, you are absolutely right, silly mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you combine the suggestion in the comments (`this.GetType().Name)` with a `[CallerMemberName]` attribute via a helper method, you can accomplish what you're looking for in a reusable fashion.

```
public class Class_Name
{
    public void Method_Name()
    {
        var provenance = CreateProvenance();
        Console.WriteLine(provenance);
    }

    private string CreateProvenance([CallerMemberName] string methodName = "")
    {
        return $"{this.GetType().Name}.{methodName}";
    }
}
```

This outputs "Class_Name.Method_Name".

You can even turn this into a handy extension method that allows you to call it from any method.

```
public class Class_Name
{
    public void Method_Name()
    {
        var provenance = this.CreateProvenance();
        Console.WriteLine(provenance);
    }
}

public static class ProvenanceExtensions
{
    public static string CreateProvenance(this object context, 
        [CallerMemberName] string methodName = "")
    {
        return $"{context.GetType().Name}.{methodName}";
    }
}
```

---

As Jeppe Stig Nielsen pointed out, you may not want the inheriting runtime type to be used, which is what `context.GetType().Name` will return. If you want to get the compile-time type instead, you can use generics.

```
public static class ProvenanceExtensions
{
    public static string CreateProvenance<T>(this T context, 
        [CallerMemberName] string methodName = "")
    {
        return $"{typeof(T).Name}.{methodName}";
    }
}
```

Comment: Related to my comment to mcjmzn's answer, `context.GetType()` gives the run-time type, not the compile-time type. An alternative could be `public static string CreateProvenance<TCompileType>(this TCompileType context, 
        [CallerMemberName] string methodName = "")
    {
        return $"{typeof(TCompileType).Name}.{methodName}";
    }` But which of the two behaviors you want is up to you.

Comment: That's a great callout and it makes perfect sense in the context of my answer.  I'll update  it to note both, depending on what behavior the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 2):

[By design](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof):

> A nameof expression is evaluated at compile time and has no effect at
> run time.

To access the type dynamically, in the runtime, you may use the `GetType` method. Just rememeber not to combine it with the `nameof`.

```cs
class Class_Name {
   void Method_Name() {
      // An event occurs

      // Is there a smart and uncomplicated way of doing this generically?
      var provenance = $"{this.GetType().Name}.{MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name}";

      // The event of whatever kind gets logged
   }
}
```

Comment: If you use `$"{this.GetType().Name}"` or just `$"{GetType().Name}"` it is not equivalent to `nameof(Class_Name)` because the class is not marked as `sealed`. (This assumes that the private method gets called on an instance of a class that has `Class_Name` as its base class.)

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen why would an instance of an inherited class not have the same type name as `nameof(Class_Name)`, where `Class_Name` is the instance's type?

Comment: @DenisG.Labrecque I tried to make a .NET Fiddle to explain what I mean: [Try it here!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ahyA0y) If you change to `nameof(Class_Name)`, the output is different.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen thank you for your input; it's true that having the child class' name stand for the base would be confusing in the case where the call occurs in the base method.